# Converting avro-schema to json-schema

Tags: avro, jsonschema, avro-tools

I want to consolidate two sets of schema definitions, one set is avro schema, and the other is json schema. In the future, I would like to develop schemas in one language and then generate the alternate format, in addition to converting all the existing schemas.

The reason behind maintaining both schema formats is a requirement to push them to schema repositories for separate tools, how ever equivalent schemas need to be available in both repositories.

(*Note: I don't want to convert an avro file to a json file, it is the schemas themselves I want to convert*)

My assumption was that avro schema to json schema would be more achievable, however, I haven't found a maintained tool or library to do this. Most recently it seems to have been tackled by (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.java-json-tools/json-schema-avro/0.1.8)

Comment: Questions asking for tool recommendations and other offsite resources are [explicitly off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)